# Enter several parameters in SQL stored procedures from python with sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sql-server, stored-procedures, sqlalchemy

I can successfully connect to SQL Server from my jupyter notebook with this script:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import pyodbc 
import csv
import time
import urllib

params = urllib.parse.quote_plus('''DRIVER={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};
                                    SERVER=SV;
                                    DATABASE=DB;
                                    TRUSTED_CONNECTION=YES;''')

engine = create_engine("mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect=%s" % params)
```

And I can successfully execute SQL stored procedures **without parameters** from jupyter notebook with the following function :

```
def execute_stored_procedure(engine, procedure_name):
    res = {}
    connection = engine.raw_connection()

    try:
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        cursor.execute("EXEC "+procedure_name)
        cursor.close()
        connection.commit()
        res['status'] = 'OK'
    except Exception as e:
        res['status'] = 'ERROR'
        res['error'] = e
    finally:
        connection.close() 
    return res
```

How please could I transform this previous function for stored procedures having **several parameters** (two in my case) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution of my problem, working only for stored procedures with 0 or 2 parameters (just edit the 10th line if you want another number of parameters):

```
def execute_stored_procedure(engine, procedure_name,params_dict=None):
    res = {}
    connection = engine.raw_connection()
    try:
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        if params_dict is None:
            cursor.execute("EXEC "+procedure_name)
        else:
            req  = "EXEC "+procedure_name
            req += ",".join([" @"+str(k)+"='"+str(v)+"'" for k,v in params_dict.items()])               
            cursor.execute(req)
        cursor.close()
        connection.commit()
        res['status'] = 'OK'
    except Exception as e:
        res['status'] = 'ERROR'
        res['error'] = e
    finally:
        connection.close() 
    return res
```